# Reload UITableView data not working properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I have an array objects received from my webservice that I use to populate a UITableView. I'm trying to implement a method that gets a new array from the webservice and redefines my array that populates the table and then reload the tableView to use the new objects from this array.
This is the method that should do the work:

```
WSCaller *caller = [[WSCaller alloc]init];

    arrayFromWS = [caller getArray];
    [self.table reloadData];
```

and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

NSString *CellIdentifier = @"productsCellIdentifier";

ProductsCell *cell = nil;

cell = (ProductsCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) 
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"ProductsCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) 
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ProductsCell class]]) 
        {
            cell = (ProductsCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (productsMutableArray) 
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.productName.text = [[self.productsMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];

}

return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [productsMutableArray count];
}
```

Comment: Change `self.table` to `self.tableView`.

Comment: It does not update the `tableView` with the new objects in the array.

Comment: how can we say, why your table does not show needed info, if we cannot see how do you fill your table view? post tableViewDelegate and tableViewDataSource methods. and say with details what is wrong(table is not reload at all or just show empty table, etc.)

Comment: @gtm it still doesn't work. =/

Comment: Yeah, is it possible that you can post the code in your `UITableViewController`? As @Morion said, we don't have enough information right now.

Comment: the `UITableView` simply uses `cell.textLabel.text = [arrayFromWS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`. But when I update the `arrayFromWS` it should repopulate the `tableView`

Comment: post the whole methods. at least cellForRowAtIndexPath: and numberOfRowsInSection: and make sure that you set delegate and dataSource for your tableView

Comment: place breakpoints or NSLogs to these methods and make sure that they are called on you try to reload your table

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource implementation is wrong (or at least the snippets are).

First, you aren't retaining the arrayFromWS:

```
WSCaller *caller = [[WSCaller alloc] init];
arrayFromWS = [caller getArray];
[self.table reloadData];
```

Second, on your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: methods, you're using a different array (productsMutableArray).

To fix that, I'd recommend to change the code above for something like (assuming that your productsMutableArray is a strong/retain property:

```
WSCaller *caller = [[WSCaller alloc] init];
self.productsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[caller getArray]];
[self.table reloadData];
```

Comment: I think, that arrayFromWS was just abstract name for array that was received from wev service. and the code snippets from table view delegate and data source methods was copied and pasted from real code

Comment: The way I am composing the `tableView` with the array is fine. The way I am changing the array with the new objects is also fine. All I need is a way to reload the `tableView`. I need the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called again because the values of the array it uses to populate the `tableView` have changed.